# Get row values only if a particular column's value does not exist

Tags: mysql, table

I have two tables in my database `students`:

**GRADE_REPORT:**

```
+----------------+-------------+------+
|Student_No .    | SectionId   | Grade| 
+----------------+-------------+------+
| 11             | 85          | B    |     
| 17             | 112         | B    |
| 17             | 119         | C    |     
| 17             | 135         | A    |
| 8              | 85)         | A    |     
| 8              | 92          | A    |
+----------------+-------------+------+
```

**STUDENT:**

```
+----------------+-------------+------+--------+----------------+
| Studentnumber  | name        | Classification| DepartmentName |
+----------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 17             | Bill Smith  | 1             |      CS        |       
| 8              | Bob Brown   | 2             |      CS        |
| 11             | Nick Fiener | 4             |      MATH      |       
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+---------+
```

I am trying to find retrieve the student number, name and major departments of all students who **do** not have any grade A in any of their courses. So I am expecting the following when I run the query:

```
+----------------+-------------+----------------+
| Studentnumber  | name        | DepartmentName |
+----------------+-------------+----------------+
| 11             | Nick Fiener | MATH           |
```

This is my statement so far:

```
SELECT students.STUDENT.StudentNumber, students.STUDENT.name,
  students.STUDENT.DepartmentName 
FROM students.GRADE_REPORT
INNER JOIN students.STUDENT 
ON students.GRADE_REPORT.StudentNo = students.STUDENT.StudentNumber
WHERE 
( (students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade = "B"  
   OR 
   students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade = "C" ) 
   AND  students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade != "A")  
GROUP BY students.GRADE_REPORT.StudentNo;
```

Comment: In future, could you please provide DDL (`CREATE TABLE ...`) statements and DML (`INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (...)`) statements - this makes things easier for those trying to help you. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Studentnumber, name, DepartmentName
    FROM Student AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
                FROM Grade_Report
                WHERE Studentnumber = s.Studentnumber
                  AND Grade = 'A'
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistype in your line:

```
ON students.GRADE_REPORT.StudentNo = students.STUDENT.StudentNumber
```

must be:

```
ON students.GRADE_REPORT.Student_No = students.STUDENT.StudentNumber
```

Also, you could change the following

```
WHERE 
( (students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade = "B"  
   OR 
   students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade = "C" ) 
   AND  students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade != "A")
```

to

```
WHERE 
(students.GRADE_REPORT.Grade != "A")
```

since you expect *all students who do not have any grade A in any of their courses*.

Comment: Even after correcting the mistype, the query by the OP is not correct. It will not give all students who do not have any grade A.